# Error with Mapping values. Can't figure out where the issue is

Tags: mysql, angular, spring, kubernetes, deployment

This is my mysql-deployment.yaml I am trying to get this to run on kubernetes but I am getting error I have mentioned the errors below my deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  accessMode:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata: 
      labels:
        apps: mysql
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-root-credentials
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef::
              name: db-credentials
              key: username
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretkeyRef:
              name: db-credentials
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: dbbuddyto_mstr_local
              key: name
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
      volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            PersistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

I am getting two errors:
`error parsing mysql-deployment.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 24: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

and the second error is

`Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "mysql-deployment.yml": PersistentVolumeClaim in version "v1" cannot be handled as a PersistentVolumeClaim: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.accessMode"`

I am trying to build a Kubernetes deployment for angular, spring and mysql.
and the mentioned errors are the ones I am currently facing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your PVC is a typo. It needs to be `spec.accessModes`, you missed the s at the end.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Edit:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        apps: mysql
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.7
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-root-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: username
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: dbbuddyto_mstr_local
                  key: name
          resources: {}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          PersistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

Comment: Looks like there was a typo with the second env value as well. I've updated my post with the entire YAML file as I can't put is in this reply.

Comment: that kind of worked but then I get this: `error: error parsing mysql-deployment.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 47: did not find expected '-' indicator`

Comment: there was a copy error, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo with `accessModes`, `ports` and `volumes` were not indented enough. They are both elementes of a container. Also fixed the `secretKeyRef` typo:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-root-credentials
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-credentials
              key: username
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-credentials
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: dbbuddyto-mstr-local
              key: name
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

**Update:**

Also fixed `labels` to match `matchLabels`, case error in `persistentVolumeClaim` and name of configMap `dbbuddyto-mstr-local`. This is important. `_`is not allowed.

On minikube there is no error now.

Comment: If I copy paste and use kubectl apply -f deployment.yml I get this: `persistentvolumeclaim/mysql-pv-claim unchanged
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "mysql-deployment.yml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.ports", unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumeMounts", unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].PersistentVolumeClaim"`

Comment: fixed some more issues, no it deploys on minikube

Comment: if only I knew underscore are not allowed

Comment: I had deleted the PVC. Added it again :)